# Stop fixed block in front of footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block located and fixed to the right of the page but there is a problem. When it reaches the footer I need it to stop there, otherwise, on some sizes, it will climb into the footer, which should not happen.

It is important that the page height can be different, maybe 3500px, maybe 4500px.

Is it possible in the script to somehow make this block stop, say, 300px from the end of the page, that is, from the footer?

```js
const navShareLink = document.getElementById('navShareLink');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (window.scrollY > 1000 && window.innerWidth > 576) {
    navShareLink.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    navShareLink.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.sidemenu-shares {
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 40px;
}

.rectangle {
  z-index: 998;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 216px;
  width: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidemenu-shares">
  <div id="navShareLink" class="rectangle" style="display: none">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this do what you want?  `bottom: 30px`, eg: `.rectangle { position:absolute; right:0; bottom: 30px; height: calc(100vh - 60px); }` https://jsfiddle.net/13pcrhn6/2/

Comment: @freedomn-m unfortunately not, the block is fixed in a different place altogether

Comment: Then please update your provided code to match the *actual* scenario, as it works fine with what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sidebar block in an element which encloses the main page content, with the footer outside of that element. Then use [`sticky` positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning).

```css
/* The important part: */

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 8px; /* This should match the top margin/padding on the body */
}


/* Cosmetics for the demo: */

.main-content {
  min-height: 200vh;
}
.main-content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25vw;
  min-height: 25vh;
  background-color: #a00;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar...
  </div>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
</div>
<footer>
  Footer...
</footer>
```

Comment: I did everything like this, but for some reason I just add a separate block that just stands still